# ng-show not showing after the condition changes to true

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an image and a YouTube video in my HTML. When the video is not playing I just want to show the image, and when it's playing I just want to show the video.
When the page opens just the image loads (as expected) and when the play button is clicked the image disapears but the video is not showing. If I delete the ng-show of the video element the video works but the problem is that it also appears with the image when then the page loads (it shouldn't).
For the YouTube video I'm using the angular-youtube-mb 1.3.2 version.

HTML

```
    <div class="video-wrapper">
        <div class="video">
            <img ng-if="!homewelcomeVM.playing && !homewelcomeVM.paused" ng-src="ommited.jpg">
            {{homewelcomeVM.playing}}
            <youtube-video ng-show="homewelcomeVM.playing" video-url="homewelcomeVM.youtubeUrl" player="homePlayer" player-vars="playerVars" player-width="'100%'" player-height="'100%'"></youtube-video>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blck-cnt animate-fade" ng-show="!homewelcomeVM.playing || homewelcomeVM.paused"> 
        <button type="button" class="play play-lg" hvm-analytics-clicks hvm-where-is="'home'" hvm-action="::'CLICK_PLAY_HOME_VIDEO'" ng-click="homePlayer.playVideo()"><i class="ic-svg ic-play-arrow ic-light ic-36"><svg><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ic-play-arrow"></use></svg></i></i></button>
    </div>
```

The control point {{homewelcomeVM.playing}} is updating correctly to true when the play button is pressed.

Controller

```
        $scope.$on('youtube.player.playing', function ($event, player) {
            vm.playing = true;
            vm.paused = false;
        });
```

Why the video isn't appearing when the controller variable changes to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `div` as a parent of `youtube-video` tag and use `ng-show` for the `div` tag:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <div class="video">
        <img ng-if="!homewelcomeVM.playing && !homewelcomeVM.paused" ng-src="ommited.jpg">
        {{homewelcomeVM.playing}}
        <div ng-show="homewelcomeVM.playing">
            <youtube-video  video-url="homewelcomeVM.youtubeUrl" player="homePlayer" player-vars="playerVars" player-width="'100%'" player-height="'100%'"></youtube-video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="blck-cnt animate-fade" ng-show="!homewelcomeVM.playing || homewelcomeVM.paused">
    <button type="button" class="play play-lg" hvm-analytics-clicks hvm-where-is="'home'" hvm-action="::'CLICK_PLAY_HOME_VIDEO'" ng-click="homePlayer.playVideo()"><i class="ic-svg ic-play-arrow ic-light ic-36"><svg><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ic-play-arrow"></use></svg></i></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Now the video shows but the height of the video is small, that doesn't happens without the new div.

Comment: Can you make a http://stackblitz.com/ sample. I think you need some css class

Comment: I have changed the div for a span and now works perfectly. I would want to know why this works

Comment: congratulations! because `div` has `block` display while span has `inline` display